# How to change the button text "View Lesson" in LearnDash

Tags: learndash

I was trying to change the text through translation but it didn't work. so

the following worked..

```
add_filter( 'gettext_lds_skins',function( $button_text = '', $post_id =0 ){
   $button_text = "Check ";
   return $button_text;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Now why this is hidden as a hook, filter from documentation I don't know

Answer (score -1):

By using the following we manage to change the text of buttons for Lessons and Topics in LearnDash frontend
Nevertheless is causes LearnDash Settings in WordPress customization to display Check,Check Check..So its a partial solution

```
 add_filter( 'gettext_lds_skins',function( $button_text = '', $post_id =0 ){
 $button_text = "Check ";
 return $button_text;
}, 10, 2 );
```